# PowerShell in C++

Tags: c++, powershell

I'm creating a program for a server. The program creates a folders and adds permissions to all folders automatically. How do I get around this error?

Here the code fragment

```
String dirname = Edit1->Text+" "+Edit3->Text+" "+Edit2->Text;
    clrscr();
    MkDir(dirname);
        system('start powershell.exe $acl = Get-ACL "'+dirname+'" \n $Rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule "'+asiart-group\GIP+'","Modify","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None","Allow" \n $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)');
        system("cls");
```

Here the error I get

```
[C++ Warning] Unit1.cpp(33): W8098 Multi-character character constant error in first **system ('......**
```

Comment: Note that you’ve used two different quotes in your `system` calls. One works one doesn’t and the error explains what’s wrong. “ is a string literal, ‘ is a character literal.

Comment: Powershell supports [Base64 encoded commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706668/503046). If you don't need to change the command often, passing encoded version would save all the hassle about different quotes, escapes and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
string s= "start powershell.exe $acl = Get-ACL "+dirname+" \n $Rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule "+"asiart-group\GIP"+",Modify,ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit, None, Allow \n $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)";
system(s.c_str());
```

Don't mix ' with ". ' means character literal and " means string literal.

Comment: `String gip = "start powershell.exe $acl = Get-ACL "+dirname+" \n $Rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule asiart-group\GIP,Modify,ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit, None,Allow \n $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)";
    MkDir(dirname);`
        **system(gip);**


[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(34): E2034 Cannot convert 'AnsiString' to 'const char *'

Comment: @АлександрДубровин use s.c_str() in the call.